# Pulling current value from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am positive that this has been asked and answered before, but for the life of me I can't find it.  I am not sure of the keywords I need to search for. I have an ASP.NET website which is pulling info from a SQL Server database into a table and some charts. I also want it to display the current value just below each chart (Step line from a DB updated with new a new value every minute). I have a SQL query that pulls all values for a specific ID for the previous hour, can I use that one or would I need a new query to just pull the last value?  And how do I then display it?

My question: How do I display a value from a SQL Server DB in an ASP.NET web page?

Comment: Your description isn't terribly clear. Can you provide code and DB schema? "I have a SQL query that pulls all values for a specific ID for the previous hour." ID of what?

Comment: My current query which I use to populate the previous hours worth data for the 9 step line charts is as follows:    SELECT HookLoad, BlockHeight, BitDepth, ActualWOB, ActualROB, TongTorque, PowerSwivelRPM, PowerSwivelTorque, AirPackTemp, AirPackPressure, AirPackFlow, StandPipe, MPoutput, HoleDepth, Timestamp FROM tbl_stats WHERE (Rig_ID = 5) AND Timestamp >= DATEADD(hour, -1, GETDATE())

Comment: Is your question: "How do I update a value on a page once per minute without requiring the user to refresh the page?"

Comment: God, I really must have asked this badly, sorry everyone.  No, I already have ajax refreshing enabled on the page.

Comment: @Trido - The steps are: 1) Retrieve values from the database and store in local variables. 2) Display the values of the variables in the page.  Which step do you need help with?  Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: So you have the data, you have it shown on the chart as a line, you just want to display the actual values in the chart? So this is really not a SQL question it's an ASP.Net question, right? There are many different ways to display a chart in ASP.Net. You'll need to post your existing code for anyone to take a guess at how to enhance it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of approaches to accomplish this (and there are definitely plenty of tutorials on the net to go). You can for example try declarative approach:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="myConnectionString"
    SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 1 HookLoad, BlockHeight, BitDepth, ActualWOB, ActualROB, TongTorque, PowerSwivelRPM, PowerSwivelTorque, AirPackTemp, AirPackPressure, AirPackFlow, StandPipe, MPoutput, HoleDepth, Timestamp FROM tbl_stats WHERE (Rig_ID = 5) ORDER BY Timestamp DESC"
    runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        HookLoad:
        <asp:Literal ID="HookLoadLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HookLoad") %>'></asp:Literal><br />
        .... etc
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:DataList>
```

But it depends on architecture of your application. You can also set the data source from your code behind and do the query there.

Comment: Kind of.  Each page has 9 individual step line charts that shows all values from the previous hour.  I have been asked to display the current value beneath each chart.  The Query is easy, I just don't know how to display that value on my ASP.NET page.

Comment: Maybe you should provide some more info (edit your answer). What have you tried? Are you using any sort of ORM mapper? If not take look at SqlDataReader or SqlDataSource asp.net control.